# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to \infty} \cos^{x^{2}}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

I have the following limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \cos^{x^{2}}\left(\dfrac{a}{x}\right)$$

where $a$ can be any number.

How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\log\left(\cos^{x^2}(a/x)\right)=
x^2\log\cos(a/x)=x^2\log\left(1-\frac {a^2}{2x^2}+O(x^{-4})\right)
=x^2\left(-\frac {a^2}{2x^2}+O(x^{-4})\right)$$
so that $\cos^{x^2}(a/x)\to \exp(-a^2/2)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.